# How can I limit number of power plans in Armory Crate?

Tags: windows-11, power-management, asus

There are 5 plans in Armory Crate: Windows, Silent, Performance, Turbo, and Manual. Whenever I press the dedicated button between these plans, it switches between Silent, Performance, and Turbo. The problem is when I want to switch between Turbo and Performance, it is sometimes necessary to go through Silent mode, which completely freezes my computer for some time. I want to remove Silent mode from my dedicated button options but I don´t know how.

Comment: link for those unfamiliar https://rog.asus.com/armoury-crate/